# How to take total TFS 2015 backup and restore them to another server

Tags: tfs, database-backups

I have TFS 2015 in Windows server 2008r2, for the disaster recovery and some precautions I would like to do the existing TFS backup and restoring them to another server, what is the best way to do this ?
TFS version is 2015 update 4 and SQL server 2014.
Please suggest me something.

Comment: Hi, is there good new for you to apply Niel's solution and the link he shared below? Did you still facing any issue? Feel free to leave comment below, thus other SO users could continue to give you help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a well documented process that is pretty prevalent online.
The official documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/back-up-restore?view=azure-devops)

1. You will backup databases (config and collection)
2. Restore
3. Install and configure TFS app tier only and point it to the restored databases.